# C++ Pointer target returning wrong value

Tags: c++, c, pointers, stack

I am a fairly experience C# programmer and trying to help out a friend with a C++ application that creates a Stack object.  It has been well over 13 years since I've even seen C++ and I am having a damn fine time trying to recall the proper way to do this.  It took me a bit to get up to speed on the Header/CPP distinction again, so there may be issues in there even.  Here is my problem:

```
//Stack.h

#ifndef __STACK_INCLUDED__
#define __STACK_INCLUDED__
#include "Node.h"

class Stack
{
    private:
    /// Going to be the pointer to our top node
    Node* m_topNode;

    /// Running count of elements
    int m_count;
    public:
    ///Constructor
    Stack();

    ///Allows us to retrieve the top value from the stack
    /// and remove it from the stack
    int Pop();
    .
    .
    .
};
#endif
```

Below is the CPP that matches the header.  I am doing  in here JUST for debugging at the moment.  I am also fully qualifying everything because I was not sure if that is causing issues with the pointers and loss of references.

```
//Stack.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
Stack::Stack(){
    m_count = 0;
    m_topNode = NULL;
} 

void Stack::Push(int Value){

    std::cout << "\nPushing Value: ";
    std::cout << Value;
    std::cout << "\n";
    if ( Stack::m_topNode )
    {
        std::cout << "TopNode Value: ";
        std::cout << Stack::m_topNode->data;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    Node newNode(Value, NULL, Stack::m_topNode);
    Stack::m_topNode = &newNode;
    Stack::m_count++;
}
```

The node class is a pretty simple entity.  Just needs to store a value and the pointers on either side.  I know I don't need to track in both directions for a Stack but I wanted to make this something that was easily changed to a Queue or similar construct.

```
//Node.h

#ifndef __NODE_INCLUDED__
#define __NODE_INCLUDED__
class Node
{
    private:

    public:
    ///Constructor allows us to specify all values. 
    /// In a stack I expect NextNode to be NULL
    Node(int Value,Node* NextNode, Node* PreviousNode);

    ///Pointer to the next node
    Node* Next;

    ///Pointer to the previous node
    Node* Prev;

    ///Value to be stored
    int data;
}; 
#endif
```

Very simple implementation:
    //Node.cpp
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Node.h"

```
Node::Node(int Value, Node* NextNode, Node* PreviousNode){
    data = Value;
    Next = NextNode;
    Prev = PreviousNode;
}
```

My main is just about sending 2 values to the stack right now via Push and seeing what the values are printing:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Stack s = Stack();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){
        s.Push(i * 10);
    }

    int blah;
    cin >> blah; //Stall screen
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Output:

```
 Pushing Value: 0

 <blank line>
 Pushing Value: 10
 TopNode Value: -858993460
```

When I hit Node newNode(Value, NULL, Stack::m_topNode) in the debugger I can see it tracking the proper value in the current node, but m_topNode references a really odd value.  I'm hoping it's very obvious that I'm doing something dumb as I don't remember this being this tricky when I did it years ago.  Appreciate any help/insight to my incorrect manners.

Comment: You know that there's a stack class in STL (Standard Template Library)?

Comment: Even if you're required to implement it yourself, I think it would be much easier to base off a vector (or array if you're not allowed any stl at all). Even if you decide to convert it into a queue later - you still don't need insertion in the middle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Node newNode(Value, NULL, Stack::m_topNode);
Stack::m_topNode = &newNode;
Stack::m_count++;
```

This is your problem. You allocate the new node on the current stack, and then put the pointer into the linked list of nodes. This pointer will be invalid as soon as your stack frame returns, and all hell breaks lose. ;)

You need to allocate the node with new.

Comment: You're using the term 'Stack' ambiguously -- both to refer to the local allocation stack and the stack class being defined.  It would be better (and clearer) to say "You allocate the new node as a local variable in `Stack::Push`, so the pointer to it will be invalid as soon as the function returns."

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having.  Coming from C# it made me rethink the use of "new" and caused a couple issues previously so I had avoided it. Then read a quick article on the differences that obfuscated its use so I moved on.  This makes perfect sense to me now though.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it make sense to fully qualify the header-defined variables like this or is that overkill?

Comment: Don't forget to delete the top node in `Pop`. And you should allso implement a destructor for your class. C++ doesnt do automatic garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Norwæ, you need to allocate your newNode with "new" because if you dont, your newNode is static and will be out of scope at the end of the Push function.

You also need to call your private members without the "Stack::" as this is used in C++ only to access static class members and functions. replace "Stack::m_topNode" for "m_topNode" only, and Stack::m_count for m_count.

Here is a working Push function :

```
void Stack::Push(int Value){

std::cout << "\nPushing Value: ";
std::cout << Value;
std::cout << "\n";
if ( m_topNode )
{
    std::cout << "TopNode Value: ";
    std::cout << m_topNode->data;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
std::cout << "\n";

Node * newNode = new Node(Value, NULL, m_topNode);
m_topNode = newNode;
m_count++;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the use of the qualifying parts.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
std::cout << Stack::m_topNode->data;
```

happens before

```
Node newNode(Value, NULL, Stack::m_topNode);
Stack::m_topNode = &newNode;
Stack::m_count++;
```

So you're trying to print an uninitialized value.  Reverse these and see what happens.